# Bottom divs jumping on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

my bottoms divs are jumping up and down when i click on the div box next to the one thats clicked

heres a link to the fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/abtPH/17/

heres my jquery

```
 $('li').on('click', function(e){
  var active = $(this).siblings('.active');
  var posTop = ($(this).position()).top;
  if (active.length > 0) {
    var activeTop = (active.position()).top;
  if (activeTop == posTop) {
    active.toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').fadeOut('slow');
    $(this).find('.outer').fadeIn('slow');
  } else {
    $(this).siblings('.active').toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').slideToggle();
    $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
  }
  } else {
    $(this).find('.outer').slideToggle();
   }
   $(this).toggleClass('active', 400);
  });
```

i think it has something to do with my toggleClass but unsure on how to fix this.....i dont want the box to jump up and down when i click on the next box

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@RickyAhn

Check out this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emgee/aALK9/) I think it does what you need.

FadeIn the new active block and on completion FadeOut the previously active one; that way no jiggle.

Updated line shown below:

`$(this).find('.outer').fadeIn('slow', function(){
                active.toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').fadeOut('slow', function () {});`

Answer (score 1):

As I understood, when you clicks on the next box, the current outer div hide so fast, make the  bottom part of the slide move up and down.

Replace below lines

```
      active.toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').fadeOut('slow');
      $(this).find('.outer').fadeIn('slow');
```

with below lines

```
      $(this).find('.outer').fadeIn('500', function(){ //after done to fadeIn new outer , we begin to hide previous active outer
          active.toggleClass('active', 400).find('.outer').fadeOut('800');
      });
```

Btw, I just want to notice on the way how you done with this slide, it maybe cause messy once you clicks on `li` faster than the duration which you set for `animation`. Anyway, it would be out of your question's scope.